# Changing site URLs in Joomla with Apache mod rewrite

Tags: apache, url, joomla, seo

So I'm trying to clean up the URLs on my site, and have digged around for information here and not figured out why I'm still getting errors.

Basically, I have a site that revolves around a search engine, and once the user sees the results and clicks on one, it goes to a URL that looks like:
www.mysearch.com/searchresults/204982398sjfdkf&thisismorejunk=junkjunk=1331

Well, sort of, but you get the point.

I want to clean this up for each result, so it looks like
www.mysearch.com/searchresult1001

I'm using the Joomla platform on my backend, and enabled 'Search Friendly URLs' and there was no problem (although it did almost nothing for me). Then before I enabled 'Use APACHE mod rewrite' I put the following code into my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteRule ^Joomla161_2/joomla\.html http://www.joomla.org/? [R=301,L]
```

(The last rule was just to see if the rewrite rule works, which it does)

First problem - My host automatically overrides the Options command, saying I can't do it for security reasons - but I figure maybe this isn't big because the rewrite rule still works.

But then when I try to enable 'Use Apache rewrite' my whole site breaks. Worse yet, I have no idea what to do next to actually CHANGE the URLs of my search results.

Answer (score 0):

**Options +FollowSymLinks**

- It is very possible that your host has this enabled by default and
  adding to your .htaccess file is causing a conflict.
- If your mod-rewrites are working without it then there is no reason
  to add it.

**Joomla Apache Rewrite**

- Change the seo settings and htaccess back to default setting.
- BEFORE! you change any of the options in the Joomla admin for seo friendly url's or Apache rewrite you must FIRST! rename your htaccess.txt to .htaccess
- In some cases you may have to give the server a min or two to notice it.
- Now change the Joomla admin settings to seo friendly and enable rewrite.

**Search Rewrite**

- If the above setting are configured correctly then your websites search results will have landing pages with nice urls.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I had actually already changed htaccess.txt to .htaccess before I posted the question... still doesn't work :(